# How to correlate proxy connections (using eBPF)?

Tags: go, tcp, proxy, ebpf, distributed-tracing

I have a simple Golang proxy, using the std libs [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#ReverseProxy)[1]. I am trying to correlate its connections / bind port *before* the outbound tcp connection is made (i.e. the `connect` syscall, if I understand correctly).

E.g. a request is made from client `1.2.3.4:3333` to destination `5.6.7.8:4444`. The proxy will make a *new connection* by binding first to some `<port>` and than creating the connection from `localhost:<port>` to `5.6.7.8:444` proxying requests and responses.

Can I catch the four-tuple describing the second connection, or at the very least the bind  on the localhost *before* the connection / tcp handshake is made? Perhaps using eBPF tracing?

I have an eBPF program that tries to sniff the outbound connections
packets but I can't get the information fast enough *before* the tcp handshake, I've tried using [httptrace](https://golang.cafe/blog/golang-httptrace-example.html) callbacks to provide this information to my sniffer but the callback (i.e. `GotConn`) provides
the connections information only *after* the handshake is made.

[1] https://gist.github.com/JalfResi/6287706